# How did pumps work during the Age of Sail?

Tags: age-of-sail

During the 17th and 18th century, sailing ships were equipped with pumps to avoid flooding. This can be seen during the opening battle of [master and commander: the far side of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_and_Commander:_The_Far_Side_of_the_World). Part of the crew act on cranks, then water is thrown overboard and other part of the crew try to repair the hull. Yet, there is no clue about how the pump work, what pieces pumps are composed of, what kind of [hydraulic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_pump) [pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump#Types) it is.

How did pumps used to avoid flooding work on those ship? What kind of pump was it? What materials were they composed of?

Comment: I can't write an answer right now, but you might like to look at the [Vasa bilge pump](https://www.google.com/search?q=vasa+bilge+pump&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRmPqOhOHoAhV8UhUIHeXKARsQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1731&bih=844) as a starting point.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I'm still waiting for your answer before accepting one.

Comment: I think Pieter Geerkens' answer pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What do you know! Thomas James Oertling wrote his 1984 M.A. Thesis on [The History and Development of Ship's Bilge Pumps, 1500-1840](https://nautarch.tamu.edu/Theses/pdf-files/Oertling-MA%201984.pdf).

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Figure 21. A chain pump. The Cole/Bentnick chain pump shown above was developed in the last half of the 18th century. (Courtesy of the National Maritime Museum from the Admiralty Collection  of Plans, #6562)